# Transmition of an 1D array of more than 20 bytes to receiver node

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I am using tinyOs (nesC) for communication between telosB motes. I am unable to send a 1D array of more that 20 bytes size to the receiver even if I initialize it using uint32_t. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There's `TOSH_DATA_LENGTH` constant that defines the maximum size of a single message. Try redefining it, according to the instructions that can be found [here](http://www.btnode.ethz.ch/static_docs/tinyos-2.x/html/tep111.html).